Study the effect of more than one parameter
I want to study the effect of S and M in the same figure, but I don't know how to do it.
M=1;\[Gamma]=.4;
sol[S_]:=NDSolve[{(1+1/\[Gamma]) F''''[\[Eta]]-S (\[Eta]*F[\[Eta]]+3*F''[\[Eta]]+F'[\[Eta]]*F''[\[Eta]]-F[\[Eta]]*F'''[\[Eta]])-M^2*F''[\[Eta]]==0,F[0]==0,F''[0]==0,F[1]==1,F''[1]==0},F,{\[Eta],0,1}]
Plot[Table[F[\[Eta]]/.First@sol[S],{S,{1,4,7,10,0,-1,-4,-7,-9,-12}}]//Evaluate,{\[Eta],0,1}] 


In this problem we have exact solution $F=\eta$ for any M, S, therefore in the plot there are several lines   $F=\eta$. Maybe you need another model to demonstrate effect S, M ?

Since this problem has an exact solution $F=η$ for any M, S, we can't demonstrate effect of these parameters. Nevertheless, we can demonstrate code to plot several lines for different M,S as follows
sol[S_, M_] := 
 Module[{\[Gamma] = .4}, 
  s = NDSolve[{(1 + 1/\[Gamma]) F''''[\[Eta]] - 
       S (\[Eta]*F[\[Eta]] + 3*F''[\[Eta]] + F'[\[Eta]]*F''[\[Eta]] - 
          F[\[Eta]]*F'''[\[Eta]]) - M^2*F''[\[Eta]] == 0, F[0] == 0, 
     F''[0] == 0, F[1] == 1, F''[1] == 0}, F, {\[Eta], 0, 1}]; s[[1]]]

Plot[Table[F[\[Eta]] /. sol[S, M], {S, {1, 2}}, {M, {1, 2}}] // 
  Evaluate, {\[Eta], 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Flatten@Table[
    Row[{"S = ", S, ", M = ", M}], {S, {1, 2}}, {M, {1, 2}}], 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"\[Eta]", "F"}]


Update 1. To plot legends inside the frame with different stile use this code
frame[legend_] := 
 Framed[legend, FrameStyle -> Gray, RoundingRadius -> 10, 
  FrameMargins -> 0, Background -> None]; style = {Red, {Red, Dashed},
   Blue, {Blue, Dashed}}; legend = 
 Placed[LineLegend[
   Automatic, {"S = 1, M = 1", "S = 1, M = 2", "S = 2, M = 1", 
    "S = 2, M = 2"}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, 8}, 
   LegendLayout -> "Column", LegendFunction -> frame, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {{25, 1.1}}], {0.2, 0.8}];

Plot[Table[F[\[Eta]] /. sol[S, M], {S, {1, 2}}, {M, {1, 2}}] // 
  Evaluate, {\[Eta], 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> style, PlotLegends -> legend,
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"\[Eta]", "F"}] 



In the above code:
How can I add a plot legend inside the figure?
and how can I change some lines to dotted lines?

@ahmed Please, see Update 1.

The following errors appear:
ReplaceAll::reps: {sol[1,1]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
ReplaceAll::reps: {sol[1,2]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
ReplaceAll::reps: {sol[2,1]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

@ahmed You should evaluate function sol[S_, M_] := Module[{\[Gamma] = .4},    s = NDSolve[{(1 + 1/\[Gamma]) F''''[\[Eta]] -  S (\[Eta]*F[\[Eta]] + 3*F''[\[Eta]] + F'[\[Eta]]*F''[\[Eta]] - F[\[Eta]]*F'''[\[Eta]]) - M^2*F''[\[Eta]] == 0, F[0] == 0,       F''[0] == 0, F[1] == 1, F''[1] == 0}, F, {\[Eta], 0, 1}]; s[[1]]] before using Plot. :)
